# Why does "use" in Clojure call "in-ns" to return to the original namespace?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

In Clojure `use` loads a lib and in addition refers to the lib's namespace.

`load` [does not change the current namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023349/).

Then what is the purpose of the `in-ns` command that is implicitly called when a lib is loaded with `use`?

```
user=> (use 'project.core :verbose)
(clojure.core/load "/project/core")
(clojure.core/in-ns 'user)
(clojure.core/refer 'project.core)
```

In other words, isn't `(clojure.core/in-ns 'user)` in the previous example unnecessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't actually call `in-ns` – it only prints this line when "loading verbosely" (that is, if you pass in `:verbose` as an option to `use`) so that you know which namespace the referring takes place in. It would also do that if you called `require` with `:as` to make clear which namespace the alias would be created in:

```
user=> (require '[clojure.set :as set] :verbose)
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/set")
(clojure.core/in-ns 'user)
(clojure.core/alias 'set 'clojure.set)
```

This is useful when the initial load causes more namespaces to be loaded recursively. For example, here's the output of `(require '[clojure.core.rrb-vector :as fv] :verbose)` (arguably the `refer` lines could use the explanatory `in-ns` line treatment as well):

```
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/rrb_vector")
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/rrb_vector/protocols")
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.protocols :refer '[slicev splicev])
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/rrb_vector/nodes")
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.nodes :refer '[ams object-am object-nm primitive-nm empty-pv-node empty-gvec-node])
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/rrb_vector/rrbt")
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.protocols :refer '[PSliceableVector slicev PSpliceableVector splicev])
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.nodes :refer '[ranges overflow? last-range regular-ranges first-child last-child remove-leftmost-child replace-leftmost-child replace-rightmost-child fold-tail new-path index-of-nil object-am object-nm primitive-nm])
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/rrb_vector/transients")
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.nodes :refer '[ranges last-range])
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.transients :refer '[transient-helper])
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/rrb_vector/fork_join")
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/reducers")
(clojure.core/in-ns 'clojure.core.reducers)
(clojure.core/alias 'walk 'clojure.walk)
(clojure.core/in-ns 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.fork-join)
(clojure.core/alias 'r 'clojure.core.reducers)
(clojure.core/in-ns 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.rrbt)
(clojure.core/alias 'fj 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.fork-join)
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.protocols :refer '[IKVReduce])
(clojure.core/in-ns 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.rrbt)
(clojure.core/alias 'r 'clojure.core.reducers)
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.reducers :refer '[CollFold coll-fold])
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.rrbt :refer '[as-rrbt])
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/rrb_vector/interop")
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.protocols :refer '[PSliceableVector slicev PSpliceableVector splicev])
(clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core.rrb-vector.rrbt :refer '[as-rrbt])
(clojure.core/in-ns 'user)
(clojure.core/alias 'fv 'clojure.core.rrb-vector)
```

Here's the relevant fragment of the source of `clojure.core/load-lib` (which is where the printout comes from):

```
;; as of Clojure 1.6.0
(when (and need-ns *loading-verbosely*)
  (printf "(clojure.core/in-ns '%s)\n" (ns-name *ns*)))
(when as
  (when *loading-verbosely*
    (printf "(clojure.core/alias '%s '%s)\n" as lib))
  (alias as lib))
```

`need-ns` is a local whose value is `(or as use)` – that is, truthy if an `:as` alias was specified or the load was caused by a `use`.

Say `(source clojure.core/load-lib)` at the REPL if you'd like to examine the entire function.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Disregard the initial timestamp. Michał Marczyk was way ahead of me on the correct answer. I quickly deleted my initial incorrect answer, and had just got around to writing this correction when I noticed Michał Marczyk's answer.**

*The verbose output is the set of sub-commands you would need to execute at the REPL to have the same effect, not the actual commands being executed.*

In the thread of execution, the namespace *is* being changed and so an actual `in-ns` command after the `load` is not needed before the `refer/alias` to ensure the correct destination namespace.

At the REPL however, the `load` will not change the REPL's namespace, so it can be necessary to ensure the proper namespace before `refer/alias`. This happens when recursively referring or aliasing.

This is more obvious with a complicated library:

```
user=> (use 'clojure.core.async :verbose)
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/async")
(clojure.core/load "/clojure/core/async/impl/protocols")
(clojure.core/in-ns 'clojure.core.async)
(clojure.core/alias 'impl 'clojure.core.async.impl.protocols)
...
```

If we were following along at the REPL, the `in-ns` is absolutely necessary for the `alias` to execute in the proper namespace. Otherwise it would be executed from the user namespace.